# How can we write data to Azure synapse dedicated sql pool from Azure Databricks using a Service principal?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, spark-jdbc

I am trying to use below code to write the data to synapse dedicated sql pool table.

The Data is stored in ADLS Gen2 and I am trying to write a dataframe into a sql table

I also have a service principal created for Azure Databricks that I am also using in Synapse as db_owner,

[image]

While running the code - I get below error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not retrieve Credential  Passthrough token. Please check if Credential Passthrough is enabled

Can some please help explain what is wrong here because my cluster shows passthrough enabled
[image]

Comment: Check this [document](https://chinnychukwudozie.com/2020/11/13/write-data-from-azure-databricks-to-azure-synapse-analyticsformerly-sql-dw-using-adls-gen-2/) if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when I tried in my environment.

[image]

You can see here, I have not enabled the credential passthrough for the cluster and still got the error.

[image]

To resolve this error, make sure you have the correct permissions as mentioned in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/synapse-analytics#configuring-access-to-azure-storage).

And also, **you can try with two service principals one for the storage account another for the synapse workspace**. Add these in the **databricks ini script** as mentioned in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/synapse-analytics#--configure-connection-from-azure-databricks-to-synapse-with-oauth-20-with-a-service-principal).

Comment: Hi - I tried this and was able to see that connection was made now and temp directory was populated but after that I get this 403 unauthorized error  - can't access external location error... Can you please suggest on the same?

Comment: 403 errors means you don't have access to it. Make sure your service principals had correct role in synapse.